# JUnit @BeforeClass annotation compiles fine in IDE but fails Maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, junit

When I write a simple method as follows:

```
 @BeforeClass
 public void setUp(){}
```

it compiles properly both in IntellijIDEA and Eclipse (using built in IDE Build).
However the same fragment of code fails a Maven run:

```
Tests in error:
  initializationError(TestClass): Method setUp() should be static
```

Should have not this error been caught during compilation?

Comment: It's not a compilation error in Maven, this is when it tries to run the test.

Comment: The `@BeforeClass` method  must be static (for obvious reason)

Comment: Andy - you are right (sorry for a badly elaborated question) - still, should have not this problem get caught during compilation?

Comment: @P.An the error is thrown by junit, not java compiler, see `org.junit.runners.ParentRunner#collectInitializationErrors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The retention type of [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) annotation is `RUNTIME`, thus it will be reported when you execute it.

Answer (score 0):

This is no different than a test failure, which is only ever detected at runtime.  Because you have a malformed method attached to your `@BeforeClass` annotation, JUnit is informing you that the tests *cannot* run due to that, thus failing the build.

Compilation has *nothing* to do with this.  You're going to want to, well, fix your tests to ensure that they comply with what JUnit is asking for.